# Register relationship with FFLIB unit of work

Tags: files, fflib

I have been trying to store a big payload as Files and link it to the object EVENT_LOG__c.In the Service layer we have few methods that are called for different events.

```
public void processEvent(String X, Object payload) {
        validateEvent();
        initiateEvent();
        processEvent();
        finalizeEvent(uow);
        uow.commitWork();
```

For a particular event, we are creating an EVENT_LOG__c and want to store payload as a file and attach it to EVENT_LOG__c.Below is what i am trying:

```
public static void createFileAttachedToRecord(
        Blob fileContents,
        String fileName,
        SObject recordtolink
    ) {
        ContentVersion fileToUpload = new ContentVersion();
        // S = Salesforce. The other options are: 'E' (external)
        // and 'L' (social customer service)
        fileToUpload.ContentLocation = 'S';
        fileToUpload.pathOnClient = fileName;
        fileToUpload.title = fileName;
        fileToUpload.versionData = fileContents;

        fileToUpload.FirstPublishLocationId = recordtolink.Id;

        fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork uow = new fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork(new List<Schema.SObjectType>{
          ContentVersion.sObjectType
        });
        uow.registerNew(fileToUpload);
        uow.commitWork();
    }
```

But my issue is recordtolink(EVENT_LOG__c) which is only created at the end of transaction as shown in Service Layer call.How do I link my created file to the EVENT_LOG__c's record or is there a better way to do it through unit of work pattern?I cant really get it to work and would really appreciate some insights.

Comment: @cropredy would really appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i resolved it:

````
        new fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork(
                new List<Schema.SObjectType>
                {
                        EVENT_LOG__c.SObjectType,
                        ContentVersion.SObjectType
                }
         );

EVENT_LOG__c eventLog = new EVENT_LOG__c()
eventLog.Name = 'MyEvent';  
....

unitOfWork.registerNew(eventLog);

ContentVersion fileToUpload = new ContentVersion();
fileToUpload.ContentLocation = 'S';
fileToUpload.pathOnClient = fileName;
fileToUpload.title = fileName;
fileToUpload.versionData = fileContents;

unitOfWork.registerNew(fileToUpload, ContentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId, eventLog);

unitOfWork.commitWork();```
````